# Evaluating the limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to \pi} \frac{\sin x}{π-x}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\sin x}{\pi-x}$$

**Book answer:** $1$

**My answer:** $0$

**Attempt:**

Let $x = \pi + h$ where $h\to0$

$\displaystyle{\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin (\pi+h)}{\pi-(\pi+h)}}$

$\displaystyle{=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin (\pi+h)}{-h}}$

$\displaystyle{=-h\lim_{h\to0} \sin (\pi+h)}$

$\displaystyle{=0 \cdot \sin (\pi+0)=0}$

Comment: No, you dropped a $\pi+$.

Comment: @projectilemotion Yep. The development by the OP was misleading. But the recent edits by Andrew Tawfeek completely hide this fact.

Answer (score 2):

This is opposite to the derivative of $sin$ at $\pi.$

$lim_{x\rightarrow \pi}{{sin(x)-sin(\pi)}\over{x-\pi}}=sin'(\pi)=cos(\pi)=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

An easy (and obvious) substitution is $y = \pi - x$, so the limit becomes $lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi- y)}{y} =\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin y}{y} = 1$.

You can also use your substitution, which would make the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi+ h)}{-h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{-\sin h}{-h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h}=1 $. Same answer, just one more step.

Answer (score 1):

Hint by Dr. Graubner :

$ \sin(x) = \sin(π-x).$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow π} \frac{\sin(x)}{π-x} =$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow π} \frac{\sin(π-x)}{π-x}.$

Set $y:= π-x :$

$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write $$\frac{-\sin(x-\pi)}{x-\pi}$$